# Prevent man-in-the-middle attacks on ssms to SQL Server Connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, ssms

I'm connecting to a SQL Server instance in a shared environment using SQL Server Management Studio. I don't want to take the hosting service's word so I'd like to find a way to discover whether all communications are encrypted. Especially the password, since it seems from [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/how-secure-is-the-traffic-with-sql-server-management-studio/9223#9223) that sometimes it's sent in plaintext and sometimes not (I've been trying to use Microsoft Network Monitor to find out if it's encrypted but haven't been successful yet.)

Even if the password is encrypted, what if someone uses the connection (as a man-in-the-middle) to enter his own data into the database? (I'm more worried about that, though reading from the database is also a problem, of course.)

So, to sum up, how can I force a secure connection or at least discover whether one is present, when I don't have administrator's privileges on the database?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server client drivers offer the ability to require encryption and also verify that the certificate on the SQL Server comes from a trusted provider.  Most drivers for SQL Server (JDBC, ODBC, .NET client, etc)  have these settings.

More information can be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067(v=sql.105).aspx